# How to count some rows within a record and make a new column with the total count?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, count

I got a dataframe like below.
I want to make a new column with the total steps count.
I got a table like below.
You can see that ID 1 has 5 steps.

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                         Steps                          |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |
|  2 | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV>                         |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to use the ‘DIV’ to count the total amount of steps by the right ID and make a new column with the total count of the steps.

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| ID |                         Steps                          | Total_Steps |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|  1 | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |          10 |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</P></DIV> |             |
|  2 | <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV>                         |           5 |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>                            |             |
|  3 | <DIV><P>Just a step</P></DIV>                          |           4 |
|    | <DIV><P>Just a step</P></DIV>                          |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Just a step</P></DIV>                          |             |
|    | <DIV><P>Just a step</P></DIV>                          |             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Is simple groupby on `Steps` column not working ?

Comment: So you `Steps` column is that long (5/4 lines) of text in each cell?

Comment: Sometimes more like 200 steps

Comment: *You can see that  ID 1 has 5 steps*. No I cannot. I cannot guess whether your first example has 2 rows and Steps in a multiline string or it has 10 rows. Moreover, you say it has 5 steps and in the example below the count is 10. Can you please add some precisions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `sum`:

```
df['Total_Steps'] = df['Steps'].str.count('<DIV>').groupby(df['ID'].ffill()).transform('sum')
print (df)
   ID                                              Steps  Total_Steps
0   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...           10
1   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...           10
2   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...           10
3   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...           10
4   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...           10
5   2                     <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV>            5
6   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>            5
7   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>            5
8   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>            5
9   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>            5
```

If need only first values add [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
s = df['Steps'].str.count('<DIV>').groupby(df['ID'].ffill()).transform('sum')
df['Total_Steps'] = np.where(df['ID'].duplicated(), np.nan, s)
#possible mixed values - numeric with empty strings, but then some function should failed
#df['Total_Steps'] = np.where(df['ID'].duplicated(), '', s)
print (df)
   ID                                              Steps  Total_Steps
0   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...         10.0
1   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...          NaN
2   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...          NaN
3   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...          NaN
4   1  <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV><DIV><P>A step</...          NaN
5   2                     <DIV><P>Another step</P></DIV>          5.0
6   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>          NaN
7   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>          NaN
8   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>          NaN
9   2                        <DIV><P>Something</P></DIV>          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
df['Total_Steps']=df['steps'].str.contains('\<Div\>\<P\>').count()
```